# Custom maven archetype doesn't generate sources defined in archtype.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create a custom archetype which defines a substantial pom.xml and includes a couple of source files.

None of the sources I define in my archetype.xml are included when generate a project using this archetype (the pom.xml is generated as expected).

My archetype.xml is located in src/main/resources/META-INF/maven and defines two sources.

```
<archetype xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-1.0.0.xsd">
<id>custom-archetype</id>

<sources>       
    <source>src/main/java/App.java</source>
</sources>
<resources>
    <resource>src/test/java/BatFile.bat</resource>
</resources>
</archetype>
```

App.java is located in src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java.

BatFile.bat is located in src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/resources.

I also have an archetype-metadata.xml located in src/main/resources/META-INF/maven which I use to define dependency version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor name="custom">
    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="thorntail-version">
            <defaultValue>2.2.1.Final</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

My root pom.xml is as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>uk.co.xxxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>custom-archetype</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Custom Archetype</name>
<description>Archetype for Custom projects</description>
</project>
```

I'm following the maven [Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) on creating custom archetypes and as far as I can see I'm doing everything correctly.

This is the result of running mvn install

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...                                                   
[INFO]                                                                            
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreade
d.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1                                  
[INFO]                                                                            
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[INFO] Building Custom Archetype 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                                  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[INFO]                                                                            
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ custom-archetype ---                                                                         
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!                                                   
[INFO] Copying 6 resources                                                        
[INFO]                                                                            
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ custom-archetype ---                                                                            
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date                            
[INFO]                                                                            
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ custom-archetype ---                                                                 
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!                                                   
[INFO] Copying 0 resource                                                         
[INFO]                                                                            
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile)  custom-archetype ---
[INFO] No sources to compile   
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ custom-archetype 
---                                                                              
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ custom-archetype ---
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ custom-archetype        
 ---
[INFO] Installing D:\dev\customarchetype\target\custom-archetype-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository\uk\co\xxxxx\custom-archetype\0
.0.1-SNAPSHOT\custom-archetype-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar                                
[INFO] Installing D:\dev\custom\customarchetype\pom.xml to C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\rep
ository\uk\co\xxxxx\custom-archetype\0.0.2-SNAPSHOT\custom-archetype-0.0.
1-SNAPSHOT.pom                                                                    
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS                                                              
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[INFO] Total time: 2.849 s                                                        
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-11T09:29:18+00:00                                     
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M                                                      
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm running the following maven command to generate my project

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=uk.co.gamma.xxxxx -DarchetypeArtifactId=custom-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=uk.co.xxxxx -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -DartifactId=test12 -Dpackage=uk.co.xxxxx
```

and this is the output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [uk.co.xxxxx:custom-archetype:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] found in catalog local
[INFO] Using property: groupId = uk.co.xxxxx
[INFO] Using property: artifactId = test12
[INFO] Using property: version = 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Using property: package = uk.co.xxxxx
[INFO] Using property: thorntail-version = 2.2.1.Final
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: uk.co.xxxxx
artifactId: test12
version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
package: uk.co.xxxxx
thorntail-version: 2.2.1.Final
 Y: :
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: custom-archetype:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: uk.co.xxxxx
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: test12
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: uk.co.xxxxx
[INFO] Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: uk/co/xxxxx
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: uk.co.xxxxx
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: thorntail-version, Value: 2.2.1.Final
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: uk.co.xxxxx
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: test12
[INFO] Project created from Archetype in dir: D:\dev\testarchetype\test12
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.281 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-11T10:27:45+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/183M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The generated project only contains pom.xml.

What do I need to do to include these files when generating a project from this archetype?

Comment: is the archetype.xml "valid"? in your post it seems invalid (closing `</archetype>`). and despite of that further insights into "mvn (debug) log" will be helpful. ..and of course the pom... :)

Comment: Added the pom and corrected the archtype.xml. I don't know what I should copy from the log without just posting a wall. There are no warnings or errors when I build the archetype project or generate a project from the archetype.

Comment: You say "my pom", you should say "which one?";) from the link: "-the prototype pom (pom.xml in: src/main/resources/archetype-resources)
-a pom for the archetype (pom.xml in the archetype's root directory).", maybe this is already the step you oversaw....and when anything else, post the output of "mvn -D install" .

Comment: That is the root pom. I do have both poms in my project and the prototype pom is being generated correctly when using this archetype.

Comment: ...`<resources><source>...</source></resources>` ..is not correct, it should be `<resources><resource>...` ..and if this is the (only) problem, you would see it in your (maven console) output.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that now, it doesn't show in the console though :(

Comment: That didn't change anything, I've editted my post to include the archetype:generate output. The fact there is no error in the console like you're suggesting there should be makes me think the archetype.xml file isn't being read at all?

Comment: the output of "mvn install" (-D for debug/more output) is also interesting/i think more relevant ...and an important information: are the files available in maven repository (%USERHOME%/.m2/repository)? (just to identify, whether the "installation" or "generation" fails)

Comment: Yes, the files are present in the jar in my maven repository. Also a class file has been generated for App.java

Comment: ..for me it works :( https://github.com/xerx593/archetype-soq54133632, though strange is, that you add a .bat file into `src/test/java` ..this directory is intended for "java test files".

Comment: I have found the problem. The main difference (Which I should've mentioned before, sorry) I had was that I had  archetype-metadata.xml alongside my archetype.xml which I used to define a version in my pom. It seems that archetype-metadata is an archetype 2.x descriptor which means my archetype.xml (archetype 1.x descriptor) was being ignored. I have now included my file generation in archetype-metadata.xml and my files are generated as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: welcome, bro! glad, you found it! :) (consider to post an answer (and accept it))

Comment: Cheers, I posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

archetype-metadata.xml is an archetype 2.x descriptor whereas archetype.xml is an archetype 1.x descriptor. Using both means anything in archetype.xml is ignored. Including file generation in archetype-metadata.xml and deleting archetype.xml fixes the problem.